# Unable to make remote desktop after the scale set creation

Tags: powershell, azure

I have successfully created a scale set using ([https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-windows-customimage](https://web.archive.org/web/20201123235215/https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-windows-customimage)) with one instance from the my custom image:

The custom image has microsoft server data center DS1 V2 and node.js installed in and a copy of my application.

From the new portal I can see the IP of the VM.
I have also successfully started it from the powershell.
However the RDP on that IP with port 3389 or 50000, 50001 are not working.
I tried to add some inboud rules but the situation is same (may inboud rules not correct).

Please can you let me know the steps required after the scale set is created in order to make a RDP ?

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to connect to the IP of the VM from outside the VNET as each VM has an internal IP address. You need to connect to the public IP of the load balancer (you probably meant that implicitly but being precise just in case).

You will also need to create inbound NAT rules to map a port range on the load balancer public IP address to port 3389 on the backend, and double check that RDP was enabled on the source image before uploading it.

Take a look at this template for an example of inbound NAT rules.. https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vmss-windows-nat/azuredeploy.json

Comment: Note that it is now possible to assign public IP addresses to VM scale set VMs directly, which adds another way to connect to scale sets without needing a load balancer with NAT rules or a jumpbox VM. See https://github.com/gbowerman/azure-myriad/tree/master/preview/network for more details.

Comment: When I try to add this inbound rule, the "OK" button is disabled with the warning "Full virtual machine scale set support for the portal is coming soon. Adding or editing references between load balancers and scale set virtual machines is currently disabled for load balancers that contain an existing association with a scale set."

Comment: You can update NAT pools using command line. E.g. in CLI: az network lb inbound-nat-pool update

Comment: Turns out that you actually can't if you use the VMSS creation template via the portal. Gives some error about not being able to modify it if a nat pool is already present. The error is actually kind of funny. Says that if you wanna fix it, then either send it with an unmodified profile or remove the profile from the PUT request entirely. O_o